# We couldn't merge the changes in DOCUME~1-LAPTOP-2HELU67E-146

Tags: windows, onedrive

I'm running into an issue the last few days with my PC & OneDrive giving me the following error message ...

We couldn't merge the changes in "DOCUME~1-LAPTOP-2HELU67E-146"

The last no. 146 seems to be adding 1 every time I get a pop-up which is every 60 seconds. Also what happens is my CPU maxes out to 100% use, showing System Interruptions and One drive as the 2 main culprits.

Needless to say, this slows down everything to almost a standstill.

My system specs are: Windows 10 64-bit, Intel Core i5-6200U CPU, 12.0GB RAM

The only way I can get my laptop to work as normal is to close onedrive which is where I keep all my files.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: The file that is being synchronized is a temporary file.  You should delete it.

Answer (score 0):

What I had to do is unlink my Onedrive account from my PC and restart my PC, after that only could I rename my documents folder back to documents and delete the additional folders.

basically, I'm resyncing my drive to my pc, so far it seems to be working. I also found a file that has now been quarantined called Exploit:O97M/CVE-2017-11887.AF which was labelled an unverified download but could not find the location based on the path mentioned by Defender.